# Did not receive expected results when using LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have the following SQL statement, and it returns only 2 records even though I have 300 employees. Does anyone see what I could be doing wrong?

```
SELECT     Employees.[Employee ID], 
Employees.Employee, 
Employees.[First Name], 
Employees.[Middle Name], 
Employees.[Last Name], 
Employees.Position,
[Work].[Work ID]
FROM  Employees LEFT JOIN
[Work] ON Employees.[Employee ID] = [Work].[Employee ID]
WHERE [Work].[Work Date] = '06-13-2012'
```

Comment: and that's a problem because.......??? Presumably it's your where clause....sigh!

Comment: check your date. just get all records from select * from work where [Work Date] = '06-13-2012'
and check whether how many records you get from there.

Comment: Assuming it is not '06-13-2012' yet, what does [Work Date] contain? Also, I'm curious about your tags. Do you have two different SQL Servers, that hold the same database?

Answer (score 3):

When using outer join filter on outer table must be applied in ON clause, otherwise you effectively get inner join:

```
SELECT     
    Employees.[Employee ID], 
    Employees.Employee, 
    Employees.[First Name], 
    Employees.[Middle Name], 
    Employees.[Last Name], 
    Employees.Position,
    [Work].[Work ID]
FROM  Employees 
LEFT JOIN [Work] 
  ON Employees.[Employee ID] = [Work].[Employee ID]
 AND [Work].[Work Date] = '06-13-2012'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want *all* employees, perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT     Employees.[Employee ID],  ...
FROM  Employees LEFT JOIN 
[Work] ON Employees.[Employee ID] = [Work].[Employee ID] 
AND [Work].[Work Date] = '20120613'
```

Also note that you should use an unambiguous date format, e.g. yyyyMMdd

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the date in the Where clause?

Try converting into a datetime or check if you don't have hours/minutes/seconds defined in the [Work].[Work Date] column data.

Try removing the join to see where is the problem:

```
SELECT [Work].[Employee ID], [Work].[Work ID]
FROM [Work]
WHERE [Work].[Work Date] = '06-13-2012'
```

How many records you have like this? 
Do all the Employee ID's match the ID's in Employees table?

If you need all the employees than you should do an LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT     Employees.[Employee ID], 
Employees.Employee, 
Employees.[First Name], 
Employees.[Middle Name], 
Employees.[Last Name], 
Employees.Position,
[Work].[Work ID]
FROM  Employees LEFT OUTER JOIN
[Work] ON Employees.[Employee ID] = [Work].[Employee ID]
AND [Work].[Work Date] = '06-13-2012'
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: then you have 2 records in database ( if u run statement as @gjsduarte says

Comment: i run SELECT [Work].[Work ID]
FROM [Work]
WHERE [Work].[Work Date] = '06-13-2012' and it gives me 2 records only is that right what about the other employees

Comment: how about the Other employees who doesn't have a record at that day

Comment: but in here no link with employeeID . therefore even ID not match with Employee table value should be displayed. are you sure about date is correct?

Comment: ye i check the date it store like the following

Comment: then simply type -> WHERE [Work].[Work Date] = '2012-06-13'

Comment: @ gjsduarte: LEFT JOIN == LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: it works now SELECT     
    Employees.[Employee ID], 
    Employees.Employee, 
    Employees.[First Name], 
    Employees.[Middle Name], 
    Employees.[Last Name], 
    Employees.Position,
    [Work].[Work ID]
FROM  Employees 
LEFT JOIN [Work] 
  ON Employees.[Employee ID] = [Work].[Employee ID]
 AND [Work].[Work Date] = '06-13-2012'

Comment: Great! Don't forget to close the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also try to check out [Work Date] column- if it also have time part (DateTime data type), then you should take that in account:

```
SELECT     
    Employees.[Employee ID], 
    Employees.Employee, 
    Employees.[First Name], 
    Employees.[Middle Name], 
    Employees.[Last Name], 
    Employees.Position,
    [Work].[Work ID]
FROM  Employees 
LEFT JOIN [Work] 
  ON Employees.[Employee ID] = [Work].[Employee ID]
WHERE Convert(Char(10), [Work].[Work Date], 120) = '2012-06-13' -- can find better way
```